# jqgrid check primary key

Tags: java, javascript, database, jqgrid, web

I have a problem with jqgrid

I use add dialog function in jqgrid. So I can add data easily

The problem is duplicate key.

I'd like to check primary key whether it is exist already when user insert data.

How can I handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [validation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#custom_checking_example) of user input. To test whether an element with `newid` already exist on the page you can test `$("#" + newid).length > 0`.